# Is there a better way to write this BigQuery Sql?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT CONCAT('method', ' ', r_type, ' ',
r_schema, '.', r_name,
(SELECT
CASE (
      SELECT count(*)
      FROM myDataset.params
      WHERE s_name= 'fileName'
     )
WHEN 0 THEN '()'
ELSE
  (
    SELECT CONCAT('(', STRING_AGG(CONCAT(p_mode, ' ',  p_name, ' ', p_type), ', '),  ')')
    FROM myDataset.params
    WHERE s_name = 'fileName'
  )
END)
, '\n', r_definition, '\n')
FROM myDataset.routines
WHERE r_name = 'fileName';
```

It o/ps the following result.

```
method r_type r_schema.r_name(p_mode p_name p_type, ... so on) 
r_body
```

What the inner query does is it first checks whether the `fileName` is present in `myDataset.params` by checking its count. If it is zero just return `()` for concatenation else if its non zero perform the string manipulation on all rows of `myDataset.params`. After the execution of the inner query just perform string manipulation and `CONCAT` it with a projection of `myDataset.routine`.

I wanted to ask is there a better way (less code) to write this query in BigQuery. I mean the query is doing its job but still.

PS: the string `fileName` is a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SELECT CASE` could be replaced by a `COALESCE` call, as the output of `CONCAT(p_mode, ' ',  p_name, ' ', p_type)` will never be `NULL` when there are matching rows.

```
SELECT    CONCAT('method', ' ', r_type, ' ', r_schema, '.', r_name,
           (SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT('(', 
                     STRING_AGG( 
                       CONCAT(p_mode, ' ',  p_name, ' ', p_type),
                       ', '), 
                     ')'),
                   '()')
            FROM   myDataset.params
            WHERE  s_name = 'fileName'),  
          '\n', r_definition, '\n')
FROM      myDataset.routines
WHERE     r_name = 'fileName';
```

Also, you may try with a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a subquery... it depends on whether the final `WHERE` clause is dynamic (is it always "fileName"?):

```
SELECT    CONCAT('method', ' ', r_type, ' ', r_schema, '.', r_name,
                 mode_name_type, '\n', r_definition, '\n')
FROM      myDataset.routines r
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT('(', 
                     STRING_AGG( 
                       CONCAT(p_mode, ' ',  p_name, ' ', p_type),
                       ', '), 
                     ')'),
                   '()') mode_name_type,
                   s_name
            FROM   myDataset.params
            GROUP BY s_name
          ) p on p.s_name = r.r_name 
WHERE     r.r_name = 'fileName';
```